# What does フェイスアップからよろしく！ 俺もあがって今日は寝るわー mean?

Tags: reading-comprehension

> 「まあまあ、まだ習うことはいっぱいあるよー！ じゃあ古倉さん、**フェイスアップからよろしく！ 俺もあがって今日は寝るわー**」

It's a scene taking place in a konbini. I know what is フェイスアップ because I looked it up(and all the other words) but I don't understand much the rest of the sentence.

EDIT:フェイスアップ means rearranging the shelves when the articles at the front are sold to make it look good.

I don't see what I can do for the rest of the sentence except saying some nonsense based on the literal translation of the words?

> Because フェイスアップ, do well! Me too I go up today I will sleep.

Comment: @keith コンビニ用語で「フェイスアップ」ってね、棚の商品が売れたあと、奥から商品を前に引っ張り出したり、きれいに並べたりすることよ～

Comment: Chocolateさん なるほど、専門用語みたいなもんですね。いい勉強になりました。先程のコメント削除させてもらいます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> フェイスアップからよろしく！ 俺もあがって今日は寝るわー

The から is "from~~" or "starting with~~", not "because~~".

The あがる means "leave (office)" or "finish (work)".

So it's like...

"Please start with rearranging the shelves! I'll call it a day, too, and go to sleep."